# What is the difference between attractor and recurrent network?

Tags: neural-network

How are attractor and recurrent networks related? Is attractor network is [private case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limiting_case_(mathematics)) of recurrent? Is there a mathematical formalism that defines both rigorously as [graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many recurrent networks have attractors. For example, the BAM (bidirectional associative network) is a recurrent network: one input is presented and the network cycles until no more changes are seen in the connection weights. The BAM can be understood as developing attractor states: Seen in n-dimensions (in which n is the number of units in the model), the state can be seen as a position. Whenever the same stimuli is presented, the state of the network will stabilize to the same position.

One reference is Chartier S, Boukadoum M. (2006) A bidirectional heteroassociative memory for binary and grey-level patterns. IEEE Transactions on Neural Networks, 17(2):385-96.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in Denis Cousineau's answer, there are many recurrent neural networks who's activities can be described as attractors. However, I would like to highlight two cases in particular, the Neural Engineering Framework, Conceptors and FORCE trained networks.

In the Neural Engineering Framework case, a recurrent neural network can approximate any dynamical system, including chaotic attractors. [See these notes for a derivation and a demonstration](https://github.com/celiasmith/syde556/blob/master/SYDE%20556%20Lecture%205%20Dynamics.ipynb). The networks can achieve certain stable states, for example when emulating a memory.

[Conceptors](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.3369) are similar to the Neural Engineering Framework, except they questionably swap out recurrent weights to generate different patterns.

In [FORCE training](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02545), a chaotically spiking reservoir can be trained to approximate seemingly any desired dynamical system.

In all these cases, assuming you have a system that can be seen as a transition between various stable states, I don't see why each state wouldn't be possible to map onto the node of a graph.

Answer (score 1):

**Only a nonlinear recurrent system can have interesting attractors**: i.e., feedforward networks cannot have any attractor, and linear dynamical system can only have one (stable) fixed point (i.e., point attractor).

The relevant area of math is [dynamical systems theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_systems_theory).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the connection between the chaos's attractor and the one context of neuroscience?

Comment: @0x90 I think that should be a separate question.